# Alt-g to clear location on selected object (selected via Outliner/collection window) not working

Tags: interface

Following the 3.0 version of BlenderGuru tutorial on doing the donut. Got to part 6 at around 2m in where he is setting up lighting.  He suggests to move the light using <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> to clear the location which results in the light going to the scene origin.

He clicks on the light in the *Outliner*, clicks <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>G</kbd> and the lamp goes to the origin.  I try the same process and nothing happens unless I click on the object in the 3d view port, not using the Outliner window.  Sort of defeats the purpose in this case.

Any chance someone has come across this and has a solution?  I will use the process that works just wondering whats up.  Tried in my copy of 2.9.3 and same thing.

Comment: Alt+G clears transform, moving objects to the scene origin, doesn't snap to 3D cursor

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I have updated the post.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts only work when you hover the corresponding editor, in this case the 3D View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>(Clear Location) to work, the mouse needs to be on the viewport, even if you select the object in the outliner. There are a lot of shortcuts that only works if the mouse is over an specific area of the UI.

Comment: Thanks You got it.  Much appreciated.